# How can I make a plot the violin plot of each crop cost

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make a plot the violin plot of each crop cost.

```
a <-4
b<- 1
c<-0
set.seed(1)
wheat <- rnorm(128,a,b)
hazelnut <- runif(128, min = -4, max = 1)
corn <- rnorm(128,c,b)
DAY <- seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"),as.Date("2022-05-08"),by="day")
ggplot(df,aes(x=DAY,y=corn,colour= "red")) +geom_violin()
ggplot(df,aes(x=DAY,y=wheat)) +geom_violin()
ggplot(df,aes(x=DAY,y=hazelnut)) +geom_violin()
```

Answer (score 1):

To create the violin plots separately, you need to combine to a `data.frame`

```
df <- data.frame(wheat, hazelnut, corn, DAY)
ggplot(df,aes(x=DAY,y=corn,colour= "red")) + geom_violin()
ggplot(df,aes(x=DAY,y=wheat)) + geom_violin()
ggplot(df,aes(x=DAY,y=hazelnut)) + geom_violin()
```

This will create separate figures for each `corn`, `wheat` and `hazelnut`. To combine them all into one plot, you can transform the data frame into long format data using `tidyr::pivot_longer()`:

```
library(tidyr)

df_tdy <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -DAY, names_to = "type", values_to = "value")

ggplot(df_tdy, aes(DAY, value, fill=type)) + 
  facet_grid(~type) +  
  geom_violin()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: wow thank you so much I couldn't combine them.